# how to delete a range of characters from a string by their hex value

Tags: ruby

I have a string, and I want to delete all characters in a specific hex range, for example 0x9c-0xff.  I figured I can do this with a single character using sub.  How do I do this with a range of hex characters?

I can get it to work using a single value and gsub, but a range doesn't work.

Here's some broken code I pulled from memory.  I don't have ruby on this computer.

```
a = "foo" + ['9c'].pack('H*') + "bar" + ['FF'].pack('H*')

b = a.gsub([\x9c-\xff],'')

puts b
```

I would like to see the string just be "foo" and "bar" without the other characters I added for testing the removal.

Edit: the wizard for question asking on this site asks all kinds of questions, saying things like "enter what you tried", or "explain xyz" and then it rams it all together into one giant mass that doesn't make any sense.  Is there a way to report the wizard as being horribly buggy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am positive it’s an *XY Problem*, but if needed it might be accomplished by force-converting the input into ASCII and producing the regex out of ASCII chars.

```
a = "foo" + ['9c'].pack('H*') + "bar" + ['FF'].pack('H*')

a.
  force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT).
  gsub(/[#{0x9C.chr}-#{0xFF.chr}]/, '')
#⇒ "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as in the example, the hex range covers no number greater than `0xFF`, you can do the following.

```
a = "foo" + ['9c'].pack('H*') + "bar" + ['FF'].pack('H*')
  #=> "foo\x9Cbar\xFF"
range = 0x9c..0xff
  #=> 156..255 

b = a.gsub(/./) { |c| range.cover?(c.ord) ? '' : c }
  #=> "foobar"
```

Note:

```
a.chars.map(&:ord)
  #=> [102, 111, 111, 156, 98, 97, 114, 255]
b.chars.map(&:ord)
  #=> [102, 111, 111, 98, 97, 114]
```